# Golang interface conversion error: missing method

Tags: go

Look at this snippet:

```golang
package main

type Interface interface {
    Interface()
}

type Struct struct {
    Interface
}

func main() {
    var i interface{} = Struct{}
    _ = i.(Interface)
}
```

struct `Struct` has a embeded member implements interface `Interface`. When I compile this snippet, I get an error:

```sh
panic: interface conversion: main.Struct is not main.Interface: missing method Interface
```

This seems weird because struct `Struct` should inherit method `Interface` from the embeded interface `Interface`.

I want to know why this error happens? Is it designed as this in golang or is it just a bug of golang compiler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have both a field and a method with the same name, which is what happens when you embed something named `X` that provides a method `X()`.

As written. `Struct{}.Interface` is a field, not a method. There is no `Struct.Interface()`, only `Struct.Interface.Interface()`.

Rename your interface. For example, this works fine:

```
package main

type Foo interface {
    Interface()
}

type Struct struct {
    Foo
}


func main() {
    var i interface{} = Struct{}
    _ = i.(Foo)
}
```